# how to send transaction with geth running in light mode on testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, testnets, light-clients, eth-lightwallet

I am having troubles to `sendTransaction` with geth running in light mode.

**Startup:**

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "light" --rpc --rpcport 10001 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --datadir /opt/blockchain/ropsten-light/ --lightpeers 10 --lightkdf conso
le 2>/tmp/ropsten.log
```

**Console:**

```
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.8.7-stable-66432f38/linux-amd64/go1.10
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

**Unlock account:**

```
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "password", 600)
true
```

**Send transaction:**

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(0.001, 'ether')})
```

After issuing `sendTransaction` console freeze. If I issue `ctrl+c` to get back to the command line console is terminated.